# Redshift - SQL - ratio of approved students

Tags: sql, casting, amazon-redshift, alphanumeric

Hi I have a table in Redshift with few students transcript records as below. I would like to work out what the approval ratio is for each university (uni1, uni2 and uni3). A student is approved when their grade is either greater than D+ or greater than 50:

[image]

I  am now trying to work out the approval ratio by university using the query below:

```
select 'uni1' as uni,
count (case when (grade > 50 and grade not in ('D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F')) then 1 end) as passed
,count(*) as total
,(passed / total)*100 as ratio
from analytics.students_fact
where uni= 'uni1' and grade <> 'Unknown';


union

select 'uni2' as uni,
count (case when (grade > 50 and grade not in ('D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F')) then 1 end) as passed
,count(*) as total
,(passed / total)*100 as ratio
from analytics.students_fact
where uni= 'uni2' and grade <> 'Unknown';

union

select 'uni3' as uni,
count (case when (grade > 50 and grade not in ('D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F')) then 1 end) as passed
,count(*) as total
,(passed / total)*100 as ratio
from analytics.students_fact
where uni= 'uni3' and grade <> 'Unknown';
```

The issue with the query above is that the field "grade" has numbers as integers, numbers as strings as well as alphabetical grades (A+, A, B+, etc). How should I go about this issue and ensure I am covering all students?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around it by splitting the alpha values from the numerical ones. This is what I ended up with:

```
select 'uni1', count (case when (grade !~* '[a-z]' and grade::int > 50 ) then 1 end) as passed_number
,count (case when (grade ~* '[a-z]' and grade not in ('D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F')) then 1 end) as passed_alpha
,passed_number + passed_alpha as total_passed
,count(*) as total
,round((total_passed::decimal / total::decimal)* 100,2) as approved_ratio
from analytics.students_fact
where grade <> 'Unknown' and uni = 'uni1'

union

select 'uni2', count (case when (grade !~* '[a-z]' and grade::int > 50 ) then 1 end) as passed_number
,count (case when (grade ~* '[a-z]' and grade not in ('D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F')) then 1 end) as passed_alpha
,passed_number + passed_alpha as total_passed
,count(*) as total
,round((total_passed::decimal / total::decimal)* 100,2) as approved_ratio
from analytics.students_fact
where  grade <> 'Unknown' and uni = 'uni2'

union

select 'uni3', count (case when (grade !~* '[a-z]' and grade::int > 50 ) then 1 end) as passed_number
,count (case when (grade ~* '[a-z]' and grade not in ('D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F')) then 1 end) as passed_alpha
,passed_number + passed_alpha as total_passed
,count(*) as total
,round((total_passed::decimal / total::decimal)* 100,2) as approved_ratio
from analytics.students_fact
where grade <> 'Unknown' and uni = 'uni3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This sounds like an aggregation.  Your query is so complicated.  It is hard to understand the logic.  But I think you want.  Based on the logic in your query:

```
select uni,
       avg(case when grade > 50 and grade not in ('D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F')) then 1.0 else 0 end) as pass_rate
from analytics.students_fact
where grade <> 'Unknown'
group by uni;
```

However, that doesn't really work because of the issue with comparing numerics to strings.  So, I think you intend:

```
select uni,
       avg( (lpad(grade, 3, '0') > '050' and
             grade not in ('D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F')
            )::int
          ) as pass_rate
from analytics.students_fact
where grade <> 'Unknown'
group by uni;
```

Comment: Hi @gordon I ran your query but it's returning 0 for all averages across all universities, possibly due to you casting to integer a result from a division. Can you please confirm?

Comment: @ERR . . . Postgres calculates the average of an `int` using a numeric representation, so that should work fine (I don't recall that Redshift works differently, but I haven't used it in a while).  You can change `::int` to `::float` or `::numeric` to be sure you get a decimal point.